# Looking for an efficient approach to resolve pattern matches

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am building a prototype framework for REST that requires the URIs to match a particular type. The different types of the URI would be as follows:

```
u:= /{name}
    /{name}/create
    /{name}/delete
    /{name}/{id}
    /{name}/{id}/update
    /{name}/{id}/delete

    and combinations such as,

    [/{name}/{id}]u

    'name' belongs to a well defined set
    and 'id' is a regular expression of the type: [A-Z][a-z][0-9]+
```

Example would be: /blogs/1234/entries/567/update

As you can see, I can chain the URIs to form complex ones.

The question that I have is, is there a good data structure that I can implement / use to handle this requirement. I am a little fuzzy on my tries at the moment and not sure that would be the best approach.

Of course, I already have this working well with a brute-force technique, but would really like a bit of guidance on an efficient way of handling this problem.

Comment: Do you want to turn your specification into a parser grammar?

Comment: @LumpN .. if it helps in being more efficient than a brute force search, then yes. I wouldn't mind implementing it as a parser as well.

Comment: Do you mean id is a regular expression of type `[A-Za-z0-9]+`?

Comment: Also, do the set of `ids` and the set of `names` intersect?

Comment: @Rob ... the names are a finite set. And yes ids are just alphanumeric strings and there will be no intersection. Let me have a look at your suggestion and try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URIs form a regular language (assuming `{name}` is a regular language, I guess it is finite), so you could create a finite state automaton to parse them.